What's the fastest way to compute the 3D inverse cosine transform for a set of indices
I have a 3D tensor in the Fourier domain and I'm trying to compute the real (spatial) values of a subset of the indices.
Computing the entire inverse transform is too computationally expensive. The classical algorithm for finding a single index in the tensor is relatively quick for 1 index but slow when scaled to high numbers. Other algorithms like row-column-frame or radix algorithms compute the entire tensor efficiently but from what I understand do not scale down to subsets of indices.
Is there any faster way to compute the IDCT of a set of "random" (random in the sense that its not every even index, just indices sprinkled throughout the tensor) indices than to classically compute the first index, and then the next, etc.
?
